# Change border of an image on Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, image, border, frame, collision

I am making a game using this function:

```
 if (CGRectIntersectsRect(object.frame, object2.frame)) {
        [self GameOver];
 }
```

Both objects are square however the image of `object` #2 is not.
Therefore when the borders collide (but not the actual pictures) the game ends. Is there a way I can have the border *"fit"* to the image, so that the game only ends when the actual pictures collide.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set image resizable as :

UIImage *object2 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueImage"]
   resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12)];

and You can set border of image view as

UIImageView *imgView=[UIImageView alloc]init];

imgView.layer.borderWidth=4.0f; //set border for image view

may this will help.